# converting a Wiki Page to a PDF file

Tags: list, wiki, pdf, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an enterprise Wiki library site collection, but I want to create a link named “Convert to PDF” , which allow users to convert the current Wiki into a pdf file. I need this link to be displayed some where in all the exsiting Wikis pages, and on any new wiki page. Can anyone advice if there is already such as capability within sharePoint 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the shameless self promotion, but as it has been a couple of weeks without an answer I am going to point you to one of my blog posts that shows exactly how to do this using a third party product that I worked on (disclaimer alert, I am biased).

[Convert HTML pages to PDF format using the SharePoint User Interface](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/convert-html-pages-to-pdf-format-using.html)

Also works from workflows and via API.